# Writing data to database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

this piece of code i have below reads data from a database, what i want to make is that when you click submit on the following form, it would write the same data to another database and when denied, it would also submit it to another different database. Can you help? since i can't get how to do it.

```
    <?php
} else if ($usertype == 1) { 
$server = "localhost";
$user = "";
$pass = "r=Sc!~";
$db = "";
$user1 = $_SESSION['username'];
$mysqli  = new Mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db) or mysqli_error($mysqli);
$overrides = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Overrides WHERE professor = '$user1'"); 
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($overrides);
?>
    <?php
echo "&nbsp;Overrides today: " . $num_rows; 
?>
<form method="post" action="dbheads.php" name="HeadWritingForm" id="HeadWritingForm" autocomplete="off">
    <fieldset>
    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($overrides)) {
         echo "First Name:&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['name'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Mid. Name:&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['mname'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Fam. Name:&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['fname'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Student ID:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $row['sid'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Scolarship:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['sc'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Phone No:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['phone'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['email'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Class:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['class'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Section:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['section'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Semester:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['semester'] . "<br />";
}
?>
<br />
<div>
<label for="comments" accesskey="c">Notes & Comments:</label><br />
<textarea name="comments" cols="35" rows="10">
</textarea><br>
</div>
<br>
    <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Accept" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Deny"><br>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: you can simply use the insert query and it's works!!! wat's the hard thing in this?

Comment: @HardyMathew guide me please?

Comment: simple it is just check with the `if` condition that which button pressed like `if(submit) { insert data in DB1 } else { insert Data in Db2 }`

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

```html
   <?php
   
$server = "localhost";
$user = "";
$pass = "r=Sc!~";
$db1 = "Overrides ";
$db2 = "ONTHERDB";
$user1 = $_SESSION['username'];
$mysqli  = new Mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db1) or mysqli_error($mysqli);
$overrides = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Overrides WHERE professor = '$user1'"); 

$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($overrides);
$mysqli  = new Mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db2) or mysqli_error($mysqli);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($overrides)) {
   $QUERY="INSERT INTO $db2(name,mname,fname,sid,sc,phone,email,class,section,semester)VALUES($row[0],
$row[1],$row[2],$row[3],$row[4],$row[5],$row[6],$row[7],$row[8],$row[9],$row[10] );
  mysqli_query($QUERY);          
}
```

Comment: But it should only insert data when the accept button is pressed. Could you fix your code to match?